# How make a correctly authenticate?

Tags: django, authentication

I'm triyng make a authenticate with Django, alterate the model adding `USERNAME_FIELD`, and create a view to make the login, but still no working. I'm using the email as `username`

```
Django==2.2.8
django-cors-headers==3.2.0
django-filter==2.2.0
djangorestframework==3.10.3
```

My code:

User Model:

```py
class User(AbstractBaseUser,
           UGCModel):

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'user'

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENRES, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=False, null=True)
    cep = models.CharField(validators=[v.validate_cep], max_length=100)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    def __str__(self):
        return '(User)%s' % self.email
```

My View:

```
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        errors = None
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        if not serializer.is_valid():
            errors = serializer.errors
        else:
            username = request.data['username']
            password = request.data['password']
            user = authenticate(self, username=username, password=password)
            if user:
                pass
            else:
                errors = 'check username or password'

        if not errors:
            login(request, user)
            user.relationships.flush_cache()
            data = {'detail': 'authenticated',
                    'super' : user.super_user,
                    'key': Token.objects.get(user=user).key}

            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        detail = {'detail': errors}
        return Response(detail, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And I add this to settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "user.User"
```

The user has created sucessful:

```
uid: "_e8f35f44afa8"
username: "vini@gmail.com"
password: "123123"
first_name: "vini"
cep: "05407-002"
last_name: "morais"
email: "vini@gmail.com"
date_of_birth: null
```

But the authenticate always fail.

```
vini@gmail.com 123123
check username or password
Bad Request: /login
WARNING:django.request:Bad Request: /login
[20/Dec/2019 23:51:03] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 400 39
```

The authrnticate is going to: `authenticate(self, username=username, password=password)`, but it's not working. I'm forgeting something to set?

Comment: Do you want to use both `SessionAuthentication` and `TokenAuthentication`? Because `SessionAuthentication` doesn't need tokens and `TokenAuthentication` doesn't need to `authenticate` users.

Comment: So if i only use `django.contrib.auth` how i can generate a token?